# How to get absolute path's of end directories?

Tags: bash, python-2.7, apache-spark, hdfs, pyspark

I have a directory structure as follows in the **HDFS**,

`/data/current/population/{p_1,p_2}
 /data/current/sport
 /data/current/weather/{w_1,w_2,w_3}
 /data/current/industry`

The folders `population, sport, weather & industry` each correspond to different dataset. The end-folders, for example `p_1` & `p_2`, pertain to different data-sources if available.

I'm working on PySpark code which work on these `A_1, A_2, B, C_1, C_2, C_3 & D` folders (the end-folders). Given a path like `/data/current/` to your code, how do you extract the absolute paths of just the end folders?

The command **`hdfs dfs -ls -R /data/current`** gives the following output

`/data/current
 /data/current/population
 /data/current/population/p_1
 /data/current/population/p_2
 /data/current/sport
 /data/current/weather
 /data/current/weather/w_1
 /data/current/weather/w_2
 /data/current/weather/w_3
 /data/current/industry`

But I want to end up with the absolute paths of end-folders. My output should look like following

`/data/current/population/p_1
 /data/current/population/p_2
 /data/current/sport
 /data/current/weather/w_1
 /data/current/weather/w_2
 /data/current/weather/w_3
 /data/current/industry`

-Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write some code using HDFS client like SnakeBite.

I am attaching the scala function  to do the same below.This function takes the root folder path and gives a List of all end paths.  You can do the same in python using SnakeBite.

```
    def traverse(path: Path, col: ListBuffer[String]): ListBuffer[String] = {
      val stats = fs.listStatus(path)
      for (stat <- stats) {
        if (stat.isFile()) {
          col += stat.getPath.toString()
        } else {
          val nl = fs.listStatus(stat.getPath)
          if (nl.isEmpty)
            col += stat.getPath.toString()
          else {
            for (n <- nl) {
              if (n.isFile) {
                col += n.getPath.toString()
              } else {
                col ++= traverse(n.getPath, new ListBuffer)
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }

      col
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below HDFS command might help :

```
hdfs getconf -confKey fs.defaultFS
```